# iPhone: How to detect if an EKEvent instance can be modified?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, eventkit

While working with the EventKit on iPhone I noticed that some events can exist which cannot be modified. Examples I encountered so far are birthdays and events synced with CalDAV. When you view the event's details in the standard built-in calendar app on iPhone the "Edit" button in the top-right corner is not visible in these cases, where it would be visible when viewing "normal" events.

I've searched everywhere, read all documentation there is but I simply can't find anything that tells me how to detect this behavior! I can only detect it afterwards:

1. edit an event's title
2. save it to the event store
3. check the event's title, if it has not changed it is not editable!

I am looking for a way that I can detect the non-editable behavior of an event beforehand. I know this is possible because I've seen other calendar apps implement this correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok it appears as if the SDK doesn't provide me with anything I can use to check if an EKEvent is read-only. I created a workaround by creating a category that adds an "isReadOnly" method to all EKEvent instances.

**EKEvent+ReadOnlyCheck.h**

```
@interface EKEvent(ReadOnlyCheck)
- (BOOL) isReadOnly;
@end`
```

**EKEvent+ReadOnlyCheck.m**

```
#import "EKEvent+ReadOnlyCheck.h"

@implementation EKEvent(ReadOnlyCheck)

- (BOOL) isReadOnly {
    BOOL readOnly;
    NSString *originalTitle = [self.title retain];
    NSString *someRandomTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", arc4random()];

    self.title = someRandomTitle;
    readOnly = [originalTitle isEqualToString:self.title];
    self.title = originalTitle;
    [originalTitle release];

    return readOnly;
}
@end
```

When the above files are in place I can simply call `isReadOnly` on the EKEvent of my choice.

```
#import "EKEvent+ReadOnlyCheck.h"
...
if ([event isReadOnly]) {
    // Do your thing
}
...
```

Comment: I have also gone through the documentation, this seems to be the only solution. :-(

Comment: Years later, and we still have the issue. Setting the title doesn't seem to work (meaning it shows as changed) on iOS 6 for instance (using an Exchange calendar), but changing the date works (date remains the same).

Answer (score 8):

I haven't worked with Event Kit yet, but from the documentation it seems that editability is a property of a calendar, not of an event. `event.calendar` gets you the event's calendar, and `calendar.allowsContentModifications` tells you if the calendar is read-only or read-write.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have looked into that property of a calendar already but it only works for birthdays. Also I'm sure this can't be determined on calendar level since it is possible that one event of a calendar is editable and another one isn't. If an event was synced onto the phone it is read-only but if I add a new event locally to the same calendar, it is editable.

Answer (score 1):

try allowsEditing property of EKEventViewController before displaying the view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. The code would look like following :
Try relating to code by logging the output of objects I use with editable/non editable events and you will understand the working:)

```
EKEventViewController *controller = [[EKEventViewController alloc] init];
controller.event = myEvent; /*myEvent is of type EKEvent*/          
if(controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem != NULL)
{
    /*Event is Editable, Your code here*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think adding this category method for `EKEvent` handles all cases where events are not editable:

```
- (BOOL)isReadOnly {
    if (self.calendar.allowsContentModifications == NO) return YES;
    if (self.organizer && [self.organizer isCurrentUser] == NO) return YES;
    return NO;
}
```